# ISAPI issue on fresh VDS

Tags: iis, isapi

I just in process of setup of new VDS box, and I faced strange error in eventlog when I am trying to access server.

**Could not load all ISAPI filters for site '%1'. Therefore site startup aborted.**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735165(WS.10).aspx

this is basic mvc application, but I cannot start it :(

Here is list of what i checked:

- asp.net is installed (2.0, 3.5)
- mvc installed
- aspnet registered for iis

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At previous hosting I did install Microsoft Url Rewriter which modified web.config. I wasn;t aware about it.

I copied whole sources and  section wasn't declared, and this caused this strange error.

After I removed rewrite section from web.config everything started to work.